# Deploying rake task to server

Tags: ruby, deployment, rake, capistrano

I have a couple simple rake tasks hosted at github that I would like to push to a remote server. It's essentially just a directory with a few classes and a Rakefile. What would be the best and/or simplest approach for deployment?

I'm thinking the simplest might be just to clone the repo on my server and do a git pull whenever there's an update. However, this would take some manual intervention and I'd like to automate as much as possible. Would something like Capistrano be overkill for this task?

Comment: Maybe the hooks are the solution. Just check this http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

capistrano fits this task perfectly, but also good would be webistrano which has predefined configurations for such cases.